# Appsync 'Batch Create' Resolver gives "mapping template" error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, velocity, aws-appsync, resolver

I'm trying to create a resolver for a BatchCreateIngredients mutation I created, but when I run the mutation I'm getting an error of type MappingTemplate and I'm not sure why.

My table's name is IngredientsTable and I'm not using any cognito verification.

**The mutation:**

```
mutation batchCreateIngredient {
  batchCreateIngredients(
    input: [
    {name: "Cookie" vegan: VEGAN glutenfree: GLUTENFREE},
    {name: "Pizza", vegan: VEGAN, glutenfree: GLUTENFREE},
]) {
    items{
      id
      name
      vegan
    }
  }
}
```

**The error message:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "batchCreateIngredients": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "batchCreateIngredients"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Item list elements can't be null for table 'IngredientTable' at path '$[tables]'"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The Relevant Parts of My Schema:**

```
input CreateIngredientInput {
    name: String!
    vegan: Vegan!
    glutenfree: GlutenFree!
    popularity: Int
}

enum GlutenFree {
    GLUTENFREE
    CONTAINS_GLUTEN
    UNKNOWN
}

type Ingredient {
    name: String!
    id: ID!
    vegan: Vegan
    glutenfree: GlutenFree
    popularity: Int
}

type IngredientConnection {
    items: [Ingredient]
    nextToken: String
}

type Mutation {
    createIngredient(input: CreateIngredientInput!): Ingredient
    batchCreateIngredients(input: [CreateIngredientInput]): IngredientConnection
    updateIngredient(input: UpdateIngredientInput!): Ingredient
    deleteIngredient(input: DeleteIngredientInput!): Ingredient
}

enum Vegan {
    VEGAN
    NON_VEGAN
    UNKNOWN
}
```

**The Resolver for BatchCreateIngredients:**

```
#set($ingdata = [])
#foreach($ing in ${ctx.args.input})
    $util.qr($ingdata.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($item)))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "IngredientTable": $utils.toJson($ingdata)
    }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that your table name is `IngredientsTable` but your mapping template has `IngredientTable`... Typo?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks like the issue is in the request mapping template. You have called the loop variable $ing, but you are passing "$item" to the toMapValues function. Can you try changing "item" to "ing" ?

Answer (score 0):

And also you are passing

{name: "Cookie" vegan: VEGAN glutenfree: GLUTENFREE}

but mapping

items{
id
name
vegan
}

glutenfree is missing and id is not handled in the resolver